# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\sin nx)^\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that $$(n)^\frac{1}{n} \to 1$$ and $(a)^\frac{1}{n} \to 1$ (with $a \in \mathbb{R+}$). However, I was wondering what can be said about
 $$\lim_{n \to \infty }(\sin nx)^\frac{1}{n}$$ and, more in general $$\lim_{n \to \infty } (f)^\frac{1}{n},$$ when f is a limited function. Is it true that they go to $1$ too? Why?

Comment: the limit must be zero because $|\sin nx| \le 1$ for all  $x.$

Comment: @abel I checked on WolframAlpha. It is indeed 1. Now this leaves open the question: ***why?***

Comment: Maybe you want to restrict yourself to non-negative function (by taking absolute values, for example), since $n$-th roots are not very nice for negative values. For $\lim|\sin nx|^{1/n}$, what happens if $x=\pi/2$?. For $\lim |f|^{1/n}$, it converges pointwise to the function $g$ given by $g(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }f(x)\neq 0\\0&\text{ if }f(x)=0\end{cases}$ (since $a^{1/n}\to 1$ if $a>0$).

Comment: @abel No, the limit is $0$ iff $x = m\pi$ for some $m\in \mathbb {Z}.$

Comment: The limit need not exist. A simple example is $x=\pi/2$, or more generally $x=r\pi$ where $r$ is rational but not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Write $f(z) = r(z)e^{i\phi (z)} = e^{ln(r(z)) + i\phi(z)}$
If $f$ is bounded means that $|f| \lt M$, i.e. we put restriction on growing $r(z)$ from n, then $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} |f|^{\frac{1}{n}} \lt \lim_{n \to \infty} M^{\frac{1}{n}}  = 1$$ 
But $f$ may very well be oscillating within its boundaries and do not converge.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} sup_x|f^{\frac{1}{n}}| \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} inf_x|f^{\frac{1}{n}}|$$
In case with $sin(nx)$ for certain $x$ (rationals multiple of $\pi$): $$\lim_{n \to \infty} sup_x|sin(nx)^{\frac{1}{n}}| = 1 \neq 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} inf_x|sin(nx)^{\frac{1}{n}}|$$

UPDATE:

On the otherside $f(x) = \sin(nx) + 1 + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon > 0$ converges to 1: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} sup_x|(sin(nx) + 1 +\epsilon)^{\frac{1}{n}}| = 1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} inf_x|(sin(nx) + 1 + \epsilon)^{\frac{1}{n}}|$$